# Variable expansion and escaped characters

Tags: variables, powershell

In PowerShell, you can expand variables within strings as shown below:

```
$myvar = "hello"
$myvar1 = "$myvar`world" #without the `, powershell would look for a variable called $myvarworld
Write-Host $myvar1 #prints helloworld
```

The problem I am having is with escaped characters like `n`r etc, as shown below:

```
$myvar3 = "$myvar`albert"
Write-Host $myvar3 #prints hellolbert as `a is an alert
```

also the following doesnt work:

```
$myvar2 = "$myvar`frank" #doesnt work
Write-Host $myvar2 #prints hellorank.
```

Question:
How do I combine the strings without worrying about escaped characters when I am using the automatic variable expansion featurie?
Or do I have to do it only this way:

```
$myvar = "hello"
$myvar1 = "$myvar"+"world" #using +
Write-Host $myvar1
$myvar2 = "$myvar"+"frank" #using +
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This way is not yet mentioned:

```
"$($myvar)frank"
```

And this:

```
"${myvar}frank"
```

Comment: Just because "${myvar}frank" is IMO the most cleanest

Answer (score 2):

This seems kind of kludgy, but as another option, you can add a space and a backspace:

```
$myvar = "hello"
$myvar1 = "$myvar `bworld"
$myvar1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is to wrap your variable expression in a $():

```
$myvar3 = "$($myvar)albert"
Write-Host $myvar3
```

Answer (score 1):

One other option is through the format operator:

```
"{0}world" -f $myvar
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a double-quoted here-string:

```
$myvar = "Hello"
$myvar2 = @"
$myvar$("frank")
"@
```