# PowerShell variables not being expanded in string?

Tags: powershell

I have written some PowerShell

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$company,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$output
)

...

$objRecordset.Open("Select Col1, Col2, Col3 From $company_Table1.DBF", $objConnection,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)
```

I am running it using

```
.\Test.ps1 -company A -output C:\test.txt
```

but for some reason the `$company` variable isn't being expanded even though it's in "quotes"?

```
Exception calling "Open" with "4" argument(s): "File '.dbf' does not exist."
At line:17 char:1
+ $objRecordset.Open("Select Col1, Col2, Col3 From $company_Table1. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

When I hardcode it as `A_Table1.dbf` it works fine ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable expansion and escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586364/variable-expansion-and-escaped-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message it telling you that PowerShell is parsing `$company_Table1` as the name of the variable; `_` is not acting as a delimiter.

You need to tell PowerShell where the variable name being and ends using curl braces `{}`

```
${company}_Table1.DBF
```

Comment: Of course, jeez. Thanks. I will accept once it allows me to.

Comment: I would imagine ISE would have displayed `$company_Table1` as a single variable. Hard to miss that.

Comment: also a common practice is to wrap the variable into a new block like this `"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 From $($company)_Table1.DBF"`

Comment: @RohinSidharth Who mentioned ISE.

Answer (score -2):

.DBF stands for database file. 
You are trying to do a select on the database and not on a table in that database.
So it makes sense this isn't working.

it should be Select * from TBL_Whatever LIMIT 0,1 ....

So you first need to open a connection to the DB file itself and then do your select against a TABLE in that DB.